# Dojo chart not working in Firefox, Explorer

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am using a script with a dojo chart inside a tab: [chart page](http://www.sensomarket.com/test/).

If you open the chart page with **Google Chrome** the chart is visible. If you open it with **Firefox** or **Explorer 11** the chart is NOT visible.

All my browsers are updated to their latest versions.

Can somebody tell me why am I getting this error?

This is my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/themes/calcite/dijit/calcite.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

  <script>
    require([
             "dojox/charting/Chart",
             "dojox/charting/Chart2D", 
             "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice" , 
             "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
             "dojo/ready"], 
            function(Chart, Chart2D, MoveSlice, Tooltip, ready){

ready(function(){

var chart1 = new Chart("He");

                chart1.addPlot("default", {
                    type: "Pie",
                    labelOffset: 25,
                    font: "9pt Arial"
                });
                chart1.addSeries("He", [
                    {y: 1, text: 1},
                    {y: 1, text: 2},
                    {y: 1, text: 3}

                ]);
                new Tooltip(chart1, "default");
                new MoveSlice(chart1, "default");

chart1.render();

});

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body class="calcite">
<div>
    <div id="He" style="width: 140px; height: 140px; "></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your issue on https://jsfiddle.net/1k6w8otn
Indeed on Chrome it works fine while on IE11 it show blank page. IE11 console however reports *Permission denied* and debugger sniffing all exception stops at some point at `getComputedStyle` definition. Quick look on dojo forum [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Bug-in-dojo-dom-style-td4007141.html) shows that there was blocking issue [18973](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/18973) opened for Dojo 1.12.1.

Switch to dojo 1.12.2 or newer and IE11 and FF renders pie chart correctly again. See modified jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1k6w8otn/2

Comment: Working great with dojo 1.12.2 and with the latest dojo 1.13.0. Awesome :)